# In Supernatural is there a reason why Sam and Dean have not tried to use this weapon to kill the darkness?

Tags: supernatural

In the latest episode of Supernatural Dean

> Stabs the darkness with a silver knife, which has no effect.

Previously Sam and Dean have spent time trying to find a way to kill the darkness but could not come up with any ideas. Is there a reason they have not thought to try using

> Deaths scythe, which should be in Deans possession because he used it to kill Death. I have considered that it got left behind as the darkness was released straight after, but even so he should still know where to find it. Death once claimed that he would one day reap god and if the scythe can kill god then it stands to reason it could kill the darkness. Sure Death could have been lying but it's got to be worth a shot?

Comment: "Death once claimed that he would one day reap god" and I say that I'm gonna be a billionaire some day, doesn't mean I can.

Comment: From an earlier episode we know that there's a "new Death", so the scythe may not be in the Winchesters' possession, or where they left it when the Darkness was released. I also get the impression that Dean doesn't actually want to kill her (yet); he's been very hesitant about it despite being given a ton of opportunities. I don't know exactly which knife he used (it didn't look like Ruby's knife to me) but he probably didn't expect it to work.

Answer (score 7):

Because they don't have it. the Scythe dissolved with Death, probably to prevent people from asking that very question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We see throughout the show, people dying, and then being reaped. This does not show the reapers actually killing anything and the word reap is synonymous with collect.

Therefore it is logical to assume that death has the power to reap gods soul, but not to kill God or any "God level" beings.